# What is this abandoned airplane parked in Tegel airport?

Tags: aircraft-identification

This airplane is parked in Tegel airport. Probably something extremely common, but can you please help to identify it?

[image: Photo of airplane]

Comment: Related: [What is this aircraft with large pipes at the flight deck windows?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/36360/what-is-this-aircraft-with-large-pipes-at-the-flight-deck-windows)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looks a whole lot like a Boeing 707

Comment: Thanks, it apparently is a 707-458 and has an interesting history https://digitalcosmonaut.com/2016/berlin-tegel-abandoned-boeing-707/ .

Comment: Like most of the abandoned aircrafts. In some countries, learning the story of an abandoned aircraft can tell you *a lot* for the country itself, especially when the owner was the country itself.

Comment: People normally include pictures or further reading links in aircraft identification questions.

Answer (score 49):

> In the far corner of Tegel Airport, to the southwest (here a satellite image), lonely a plane with a special story rots: The Boeing 707 was a gift from the manufacturer to the Lufthansa and landed in 1986 by tricky preparations as the first Lufthansa aircraft in West -Berlin. Otherwise only Allied aircraft could fly through the east corridor. Lufthansa donated the plane to the Berlin Technikmuseum, which, however, can not do anything with it. Every now and then, the airport fire brigade on the Boeing exercises in case of emergency.

https://www.tagesspiegel.de/mediacenter/fotostrecken/berlin/flughafen-tegel-das-vergessene-flugzeug/13531996.html

Comment: .. poor thing :-(

Comment: I wonder if a Kickstarter or other fund could be started to restore it to its former glory.  See if Lufthansa wants to contribute.

Comment: Unlikely, as they are not willing to fund the Constellation project: https://www.nzz.ch/mobilitaet/luftfahrt/lufthansa-oldie-projekt-super-constellation-im-sinkflug-ld.1367157 (in German)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a 707-458, due to its four engines on its wings.
[image]